# Qt paint figures at one window

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

1. I create  class Widget, it creates window, this class paints something on the window (i.e. it works as I want).
2. I create yet one class, Circle, I want to paint on the window of class Widget.
3. I pass adress of Widget and try to paint on Widget using  QPainter paint (address of Widget); (in the instance of Circle) but i don't see anything.

I've tried to make code as shorter as possible during the execution of program I type out address of object Widget. It doesn't change. It means that the address of Widget was passed right.

Everywhere, where I type out address of Widget I receive the same address. Here is the code:

header Widget

```
            class Widget : public QWidget
            {
                public:
                int  mi,mcount;
                Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
                QPaintEvent *ev;
                virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
            void drawcircle();
            };
```

Widget.cpp

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(ev);

    qDebug()<<this<<"\n";  //
}

        void Widget::drawcircle()
        {
        QPainter paint(this);
        paint.drawEllipse(0,0,100,100);
        }


void Widget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
{    this->drawcircle(); }
```

header Circle.h

```
        class Circle :public QWidget
        {
            public:
            Circle(Widget *widget);    // i do trick here!!!
            Widget *mwidg;
        QPaintEvent *ev;

        virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
        void drawcircle(Widget *mwidg);
        };
```

Circle.cpp

```
    Circle::Circle(Widget *widget)
        {
        qDebug()<<"circle widget"<<widget;
        QWidget::paintEvent(ev);
        mwidg=widget;
        qDebug()<<"\n"<<mwidg;
        }



    void Circle::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev)
    {  qDebug()<<"circle paintEvent mwidget"<<mwidg<<"\n";
    this->drawcircle(mwidg);
        }


        void Circle::drawcircle(Widget *mwidg)
            {
                QPainter paint(mwidg);
                paint.drawEllipse(20,10,40,40);
            paint.drawLine(0,0,500,500);
            }
```

main

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        Widget *w=new Widget;

            qDebug()<<"main address of widget"<<w<<"\n";
        Circle *f=new Circle(w);
        w->show();

        return a.exec();
        }
```

program is compiled and linked successful

Comment: QWidget::paintEvent() is protected. And also, the Circle::paintEvent doesn't get called, since you didn't add the circle as a child of the main Widget.

Comment: i declare it as public. and furthermore if i  write in main.cpp Widget *w=new Widget;  w->paintEvent()  , Qt'll allow me to do this.  it means that  paintEvent is public.  do i think right?

Comment: You should not call paintEvent() yourself, the framework will do this when the widget needs to be painted. Just put the drawing code you want inside the paintEvent() and it will get called when needed.

Comment: should i do this always?  but  i do this in Widget and it works. why shouldn't i do this in Circle?

Comment: i've tried to change this -  nothing, result still is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , thank you for your attempts to help
 but all that i was needing:

this -> setParent(widget);

in costructor Circle::Circle, if somebody'll want to see my solve,one can see that figures are moved

source code is here  [source code](http://narod2.yandex.ru/disk/14615428001/myfirst.zip)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve?  You can only paint on any widget in it's own paintEvent() handler, and you should not call paintEvent() yourself, it won't work.  Also, get rid of the QPaintEvent member variables.

I would suggest that you make Circle a child of Widget, and then paint the circle from Circle::paintEvent().  Alternatively, use QGraphicsView.